# Disable input with cshtml

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to disable an input box based on if `SuspendActivityAtNight` is true or false. `SuspendActivityAtNight` is obtained from a checkbox. The problem is the input is enabled/disabled correctly to begin with. But when I click/unclick the checkbox, the input doesn't toggle for enabled/disabled state

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label asp-for="Item1.SuspendActivity" class="col-md-8 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input asp-for="Item1.SuspendActivity" type="time" class="form-control" disabled="@(!Model.Item1.SuspendActivityAtNight)" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Item1.SuspendActivity" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Razor is server side. It doesn’t affect what happens client side so you’ll have to write the needed JavaScript code to handle it, unless you send every change to the server.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can i write that cshtml file as well?

Comment: You will need to have javascript (or jquery) function to do this toggle behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this change function to your razor file's scripts section (or create one if one is not there). Also replace chkBoxId and textboxId with your respective real html control ids.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#chkBoxId').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
           $("#textboxId").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#textboxId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```